# AWS Neptune - Submit Query with empty string crashes

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop3, amazon-neptune

Script with `" "` (empty space with space) works fine but `""` empty string crashes.

```
gremlin> g.addV("Test").property("title", "Test node 1").property("a", "")
{"requestId":"111xxxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx","code":"MalformedQueryException","detailedMessage":"Query parsing failed at line 1, character position at 62, error message : no viable alternative at input 'g.addV(\"Test\").property(\"title\",\"Test node 1\").property(\"a\",\"\"'"}
Type ':help' or ':h' for help.
Display stack trace? [yN]


gremlin> g.addV("Test").property("title", "Test node 1").property("a", " ")
==>v[98b22f0f-6be0-fb11-38cc-066bf7e17051]
```

---

This works fine with NEO4J Gremlin, so I doubt this is a Gremlin issue. Is this a Neptune bug or feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that to be a problem with Neptune as empty string should be an acceptable value for most graph systems. As a workaround have you tried writing your traversal as:

```
g.addV("Test").property("title", "Test node 1").property("a", '')
```

meaning, use single quotes to represent the empty string rather than double quotes? Perhaps that is a workaround for this query parsing problem.

Comment: thanks. they will fix this soon https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-neptune-samples/issues/2

Comment: single quote throws this `gremlin> g.addV("Test").property("title", "Test node 1").property("a", '')
{"requestId":"77c4c526-692e-4b5e-82c2-a602fdc3b331","code":"MalformedQueryException","detailedMessage":"Query parsing failed at line 1, character position at 62, error message : no viable alternative at input 'g.addV(\"Test\").property(\"title\",\"Test node 1\").property(\"a\",'''"}
`

basically I just wanted to verify whether this is a Neptune related issue. So this issue is resolved.